# Cut a specific part of String in loop

Tags: java, string

I have a String like this:

```
String content = "{"begin"bf3b178a70.jpg","end",....},{"id":,"f06190e8938.jpg","end",....}"
```

and i want to cut out the image ID like this:

```
bf3b178a70.jpg
f06190e893.png
```

and after that, i want compose the image ID with a new url like this:

```
url.com/image/bf3b178a70.jpg
url.com/image/f06190e893.png
```

I begin with substring() to cut the first part and with `content.split(""id":,");` but i have problems with a string array and normal string. I used the string array with a for-loop, because the real string is very long.

Will someone please help me?

Comment: your string does not seem right

Comment: seems alot like your string is in JSON format (though what you've actually typed in here is not valid json), in which case just use a standard JSON parsing library like JSONObject or GSON or Jackson

Comment: i have cut out nonrelevant stuff from the string

Comment: Yeah, your "string" is JSON (though slightly garbled).  Parse the JSON into a Map (JSON object) and the data will be easy to access.

Comment: can you post a code snippet how to use the Json Parser in the correct way? - specific for this problem

Comment: Your code does not compile; it looks like you are missing backslashes from your string literal - can you please correct the code, so we can see exactly what your input string is.

Comment: "cutting out nonrelevant stuff" is a problem if you need an example showing how to use a JSON parser; can you post or link to an uncut sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first blush, it looks like your string is formatted as [JSON](http://json.org/).  If that's the case you can use the [JSON.org Java parser](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) or one of the many other parsers listed on the [JSON.org site](http://json.org/) to break it down, or just follow the syntax diagrams they give; simple string-chopping is inadvisable since JSON is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

I'm going to assume for the moment that you're receiving a JSON array-of-objects (square brackets around, comma separated), and that you are either reading from a file or a Web service, either of which provides an `InputStream`.  If you have something else, you can pass a `Reader` or a plain `String` to the `JSONTokener` constructor, or if you have a byte array you can wrap it in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and pass that in.

I don't have a JDK handy to even check if this compiles :-) but here goes.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.*;

public class ImageListProcessor
{
    public static ArrayList<URL> processList(InputStream toProcess, URL baseURL)
        throws JSONException, MalformedURLException
    {
        JSONTokener toProcessTokener = new JSONTokener(toProcess);
        JSONObject toProcessResponse = new JSONObject(toProcess);
        if (!toProcessResponse.isNull("error")) {
            // it's an error response, probably a good idea to get out of here
            throw new JSONException("Response contains error: " + toProcessResponse.get("error"));
        }
        JSONArray toProcessArray = toProcessResponse.getJSONArray("items");
        int len = toProcessArray.length();
        ArrayList<URL> result = new ArrayList<URL>(len);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            JSONObject imageRecord = toProcessArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String imagePath = imageRecord.getString("image");
            // if you want to remove the date portion of the path:
            imagePath = imagePath.substring(1 + imagePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
            URL combinedURL = new URL(baseURL, imagePath);
            result.add(combinedURL);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, that is an uncut sample. {"id":2683,"up":4,"down":2,"created":140,"image":"2014\/08\/12\/79092c524b9fb94e‌​.jpg","thumb":"2014\/08\/12\/79092c524b9fb94e.jpg","fullsize":"","source":"","use‌​r":"","mark":6}

Comment: @cekayyy, I assume you're receiving a JSON array of those objects (a comma-separated list wrapped in square brackets) and have designed accordingly.

Comment: nice! thank you Jeffrey! It works fine if i edit the first line of json string. Only one problem still exist. The String came from a web service and starts with:{"atEnd":false,"atStart":true,"error":null,"items": only then start the square brackets with [{"id":270842,.... The exception comes up with JsonArray have to start with [ . That mean i can't use JsonArray for this?

Comment: @cekayyy, that's an outer JsonObject around the JsonArray.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: okay, good idea but i get the exception, that JSONObject["image"] not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ReplaceDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = 
              "User clientId=23421. Some more text clientId=33432. This clientNum=100";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(clientId=)(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Masking: " + m.group(2));
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1) + "***masked***");
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result);
}
}
```